# How to insert reference in query dialog lookup?

Tags: jquery, axapta, lookup, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

If I have two *Lookup* in a *Query Promt* correlated between them, there is a way to insert its relation in these lookup?

**Example** :

VENDTABLE Query Promt fields *SegmentId* and *SubSegmentId*.

If I select determinate value in Field SegmentId I want to select all SubSegmentId having has the same as that put in SegmentId, vice versa if I selected SubSegmentId (with specific SegmentId) I want to filter in SegmentId .

The object is this:
[image: Query Promt]

How to create a relation between two filed ?

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the relation between the fields on the table, however it does not affect the query form.

This is probably due to the implementation problem: How to do a lookup on zip codes if the country selected is, say "DNK,USA"?

It does work on a form (with bound fields) because you can only choose one value for country.

So the answer is, it cannot be done in a query form, you can however create your own (dialog) form and [override the lookup there](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axaptavsme/archive/2013/05/24/custom-lookup-for-dialog-fields-in-axapta).